# SQL Server reporting database catalog and Reporting Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am doing some research on migrating our SSRS 2005 to 2015. ATM I have a DB VM that host the production DB, Report DB, Report TempDB, and also run the Reporting Services/Server. Highly problematic as you can see.

I am considering the following scenarios for the new environment (don't worry about the $$$ atm):

- production db on 1 VM, Report DB and Report TempDB on another VM, Reporting Services on another VM **(3 VMs)**
- production db+Report DB+Report TempDB on 1 VM, Reporting Services on another VM **(2 VMs)**
- production db on 1 VM, Report DB+Report TempDB+Reporting Services on another VM **(2 VMs)**
- production db on 1 VM, transactionally replicated to another VM which also host Report DB+Report TempDB+Reporting Services.  Reporting services only use the replicated DB as source for reports. **(2 VMs)**

DR is not an issue, the agreed RTO is 4 hrs(!)

We don't have a lot of users, but a lot of reports (> 200), some are graphic intensive.  Ad-hoc plus off-hours report snapshots created.  We are experiencing some timeout issues. (once or twice a day)

I am looking for one of the scenarios above that gives the best performance.

Can anyone suggest which one is the most sensible approach?  Can provide more info.

Thanks in advance.  WM

Comment: I suggest you try to analyse the load on your existing system. Is the report tempdb used much? (probably not). Have any issues arisen due to reading directly from prod? I will say if you use your last option you basically have a standalone server for reporting purposes which might make config/dev a lot easier in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "production db" is some kind of OLTP system then this should be completely separated from any reporting or analysis activity. If you have the resources then I suggest creating an AlwaysOn group (the successor to mirroring in SQL 2005) and use the secondary replica as the source for your reports, e.g.

1. production db (1 VM)
2. AlwaysOn secondary replica of production, in read only mode (1
   VM)
3. ReportServer db & reporting services (1 VM)

This keeps your production db from being impacted by reporting queries, by offloading the work to the replica (which also doubles as your HA/failover db) and keeps the report server components nicely packaged up on a single VM, which should be sufficient based on your description of the workload.

Comment: I agree with the alwaysOn but then excuse my ignorance do I have to set up a cluster for alwaysOn?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific - point 2 refers to an AlwaysOn Availability Group and these require each Windows host to be part of a Windows Server Failover Cluster. In this scenario the servers in #1 and #2 are in a WSFC and the #3 server is standalone. How up to date does your report data need to be? Perhaps you can use log shipping instead to create a database in STANDBY mode to be used for reporting instead.

Comment: Report data can have a couple of minutes delay. Thanks mate